# invoking OpenWhisk actions from a Python app?

Tags: python, openwhisk

I wonder what is the easiest way to invoke an OpenWhisk action from a Python app?
Perhaps something equivalent to https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-client-js/ but in Python. I know that there used to be a Python-based CLI (https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-client-python), but I haven't found any documentation on how to reuse it from my Python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoking actions from a Python application will need you to send a HTTP request to the platform API. There is no official OpenWhisk SDK for Python.

The example code shows how to invoke the platform API using the `requests` library.

```
import subprocess
import requests

APIHOST = 'https://openwhisk.ng.bluemix.net'
AUTH_KEY = subprocess.check_output("wsk property get --auth", shell=True).split()[2] 
NAMESPACE = 'whisk.system'
ACTION = 'utils/echo'
PARAMS = {'myKey':'myValue'};
BLOCKING = 'true'
RESULT = 'true'

url = APIHOST + '/api/v1/namespaces/' + NAMESPACE + '/actions/' + ACTION
user_pass = AUTH_KEY.split(':')
response = requests.post(url, json=PARAMS, params={'blocking': BLOCKING, 'result': RESULT}, auth=(user_pass[0], user_pass[1]))
print(response.text)
```

Swagger documentation for full API is available [here](http://petstore.swagger.io/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/master/core/controller/src/main/resources/apiv1swagger.json).

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/issues/450) to create a Python client library to make this easier.